# Redirecting the user from codeigniter to magento using magento

Tags: magento-1.7, redirect

I am using codeigniter and Magento in same domain. And I have created a function in codeigniter to check the magento customer log in status. If the customer is not logged in magento then return to magento login page but it is not redirecting it and I used just php header function but I want to use magento function and as well the reason.

```
public function loggedIn(){

    //$customerInfo = array();
    $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $fullPath = $dir.'/magento/app/Mage.php';
    echo $fullPath;

    require_once( "$fullPath" );
    umask(0);

    // Initialize Magento
    Mage::app();

    // You have two options here,
    // “frontend” for frontend session or “adminhtml” for admin session
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
if($session->isLoggedIn()){
    echo "Logged In";
    return $session->getCustomer();
    }
    else{
    echo "Logged out";
    //header('Location:http://localhost/magento/customer/account');
    $url = "http://localhost/magento/customer/account";
     Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url); 
    }

 }
```

thanks :)

Comment: This will provide a better guide. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_config/edit/web#session_cookie_management_field_descriptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have forgot to call the sendResponse Method.

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
```

Comment: @roman204...Hey thank you very much...Its working... through google I found this only and sendResponse() was missing ... thanks :)